# add axis only if user specifies range

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I am trying to get a shiny app to specify the axis range if the user changes the default values.
As of now, the user can filter the data based on a specified value (filter is always active which is why the defaults are such extreme values), but I want to provide the functionality to also specify the axis range as that same value.

The sample code is my attempt at doing this, but I would also like to be able to have the axis be default for the max value if they only specify a min value (in the 2nd image, this would mean that the axis would have a minimum of 3 and a max set by the default.  I realize that is the case in the example I provided, but I want the user to be able to set the min to -2 and have the axis expand to see white space out to x=-2 with the max still set at the default) and I am not sure how to begin constructing that.

```
#Check packages to use in library
{
library('shiny') #allows for the shiny app to be used. I am using V0.13.1
library('ggvis') #allows for interactive ploting. I am using V0.4.2
library('dplyr') #I am using V0.4.3
}

alldata <- iris

#establish options for drop down menus
{
specieschoices <- unique(as.character(alldata$Species))
petalwchoices <- unique(as.character(alldata$Petal.Width))
petallchoices <- unique(as.character(alldata$Petal.Length))
sepallchoices <- unique(as.character(alldata$Sepal.Length))
sepalwchoices <- unique(as.character(alldata$Sepal.Width))
}
# UI

ui<-fluidPage(
titlePanel("Explorer"),
fluidRow(
column(8,
       ggvisOutput("plot1")
),
column(4,
       wellPanel(
         h4("Data Variables"),
         selectInput(inputId = "x", label="Select x-axis Variable:", choices=as.character(names(alldata[,1:4])),selected='Petal.Length', multiple = FALSE),
         selectInput(inputId = "y", label="Select y-axis Variable:", choices=as.character(names(alldata[,1:4])),selected='Petal.Width', multiple = FALSE)
       )),
column(4,
         wellPanel(
             wellPanel(
               numericInput(inputId = "minxaxis", label="Specify x axis min", value = -999999999),
               numericInput(inputId = "maxxaxis", label="Specify x axis max", value = 999999999),
               numericInput(inputId = "minyaxis", label="Specify y axis min", value = -999999999),
               numericInput(inputId = "maxyaxis", label="Specify y axis max", value = 999999999)
             )
         ))
))

#SERVER
server<-function(input,output,session)
{

#Set up reactive variables
filteredData <- reactive({
  minX <- input$minxaxis
  maxX <- input$maxxaxis
  minY <- input$minyaxis
  maxY <- input$maxyaxis
  a <- which(names(alldata)==input$x)
  xvariable <- as.numeric(alldata[,a])
  b <- which(names(alldata)==input$y)
  yvariable <- as.numeric(alldata[,b])

# Apply filters
m <- alldata %>% filter(
  xvariable >= minX,
  xvariable <= maxX,
  yvariable >= minY,
  yvariable <= maxY
)
m <- droplevels(as.data.frame(m))
m
})

vis <- reactive({

xvar <- prop("x", as.symbol(input$x))
yvar <- prop("y", as.symbol(input$y))
minX <- input$minxaxis
maxX <- input$maxxaxis
minY <- input$minyaxis
maxY <- input$maxyaxis

p1 = filteredData() %>%
  ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar) %>%
  layer_points(size.hover := 200,
               fillOpacity:= 0.5, fillOpacity.hover := 1
  ) %>%

  # Specifies the size of the plot
  set_options(width = 800, height = 450, duration = 0)


#################### THIS IS THE PART THAT I NEED HELP ON ####################### 
# %>%>
# if (minX != -999999999 & maxX != 999999999) {
#   add_axis("x", values = minX:maxX)
# }
# else if (minY != -999999999 & maxY != 999999999) {
#   add_axis("y", values = minY:maxY)
# }
#################################################################################

})

#Actually plots the data
vis %>% bind_shiny("plot1")
}

#Run the Shiny App to Display Webpage
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[default view of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV5Ol.png)

[image: Min x axis changed to 3]

Comment: Not what I see. `Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5661
Warning: Error in match.arg: 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector`. May need to review all the version numbers, and `sessionInfo()` values.

Comment: @42- my apologies, I forgot to include the package dplyr and it was working on my machine because the package was loaded from previous use.  My sample code has been corrected to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your axis limits to either NA or the chosen value using a logic statement and the input value, e.g., `input$minxaxis`.

```
minX = if(input$minxaxis == -999999999) {NA} else {input$minxaxis}
maxX = if(input$maxxaxis == 999999999) {NA} else {input$maxxaxis}
minY = if(input$minyaxis == -999999999) {NA} else {input$minyaxis}
maxY = if(input$maxyaxis == 999999999) {NA} else {input$maxyaxis}
```

Then you can use `scale_numeric` to set the limits of the axes via `domain`.  If one of the limits is NA then the default domain value is used instead.

```
p1 = filteredData() %>%
    ggvis(x = xvar, y = yvar) %>%
    layer_points(size.hover := 200,
               fillOpacity:= 0.5, fillOpacity.hover := 1) %>%
    scale_numeric("x", domain = c(minX, maxX), clamp = TRUE) %>%
    scale_numeric("y", domain = c(minY, maxY), clamp = TRUE)
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, however, now when a negative sign is entered in any field, the app crashes if a numeric value is not entered quick enough after the negative sign.  How would a delay or an action button (whichever would be easiest in my case) fix this issue?

Comment: shiny's validate might be an option as well.

Comment: @User247365 Not sure, sounds like it is worth an additional question.  It does seem like some sort of pause is needed to give plenty of time to type in the first digit.